# Как отключить нажатия на экран во время работы ProgressBar

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Как отключить нажатие на этих поля во время загрузки попробовал эту но не получилось  android:clickable="false" в xml progresBar как сделать не могу понять кто нибудь спасибо заранее

---

вот эти поля  как сделать не могу понять

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С виду это диалог который висит над активностью. Можно отключить нажатия за пределами диалога и тогда не нужно будет переживать за нажатия на поля ввода:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Но если вы всё-таки намерены отключать нажатия на поля, то это можно сделать так:

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

Код выше можно изменить для ваших целей.

Comment: Спасибо ) помог